# Extracting two columns from a data frame and merging them with a second data frame

Tags: r, database

I'm having some trouble working with data frames.

I have a data frame (df1, see image 1), from which I need to extract the IDs from the last column (comments), this I can do with the next line:

```
genes <- sapply(df1$Comment, function(x){
  paste(substring(x, as.numeric(gregexpr("SL1344_RS", x)[[1]]), 
                  as.numeric(gregexpr("SL1344_RS", x)[[1]]) + 13), collapse=";")
  })
```

now I need to merge this ID with their correspondent frequency value, under the column "freq", so I end up with two columns, one with the ID and the next with their frequency value.

Finally, I need to change the ID with their protein name, this information It´s within df2 (see image), where you can see each ID is related to a gene product under the column of "Product".

Here is the code that generates `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  gene = c("SL1344_RS000040", "SL1344_RS000095", "SL1344_RS000105"),
  freq = c(7, 21 , 51))

df2 <- data.frame(
  code = c("SL1344_RS000095", "SL1344_RS000040", "SL1344_RS000105"),
  product = c("Product C", "Product A", "Product B"))
```

Comment: Hi, please don't use images of code/data on Stack Overflow, consider our guidelines on how to provide a [mcve], you may want to read: [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now I need to merge this ID with their correspondent frequency value, under the column "freq", so I end up with two columns, one with the ID and the next with their frequency value.

You can achieve that by simply doing

```
genes.freq <- cbind(genes, df1$freq)
```

> Finally, I need to change the ID with their protein name, this information It´s within df2 (see image), where you can see each ID is related to a gene product under the column of "Product".

This is simply a search in df2 where you want to get the index of the match.

```
names <- df2$Product[ match(genes.freq$gene, df2$Code) ]

genes.freq.names <- cbind(
    genes.freq, names)
```

Here is a simple toy example

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  gene = c("SL1344_RS000040", "SL1344_RS000095", "SL1344_RS000105"),
  freq = c(7, 21 , 51))

df2 <- data.frame(
  code = c("SL1344_RS000095", "SL1344_RS000040", "SL1344_RS000105"),
  product = c("Product C", "Product A", "Product B"))

df1$Product.Names <- df2$product[ match(df1$gene, df2$code) ]

df1
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This indeed solved the issue, thanks for your quick answer!!

Comment: I have a new little request thogh. There're some genes that have a composed ID; for instance, "SL1344_RS09335;SL1344_RS09330", Is there a way to divide them into two separate rows with the former frequency value for both of them? Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean a split? If yes, you should open a new question. If you want me to help, try to link me or post the link to the question here as a comment. And please add a simple toy example with the expected output. See how I created df1. All the best!

Comment: PS: In any cae, you may want to look at `strsplit(df$ColumnWithTheString, ";")`

Comment: Upvote my answer as useful, If you don't mind. Thanks.